# Unity - Google Ads for iOS game- use of Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, ads

So, I have developed and released a iOS (and Android) game developed on Unity. Now I was trying to use google ads to increase installs of my game. I was able to create an add campaign for android but facing a hurdle for iOS.

Google Ads require me to use a "conversion tracker" for iOS Add campaign. There are various app analytics but the one which i was thinking of using is google Firebase.

I am not able to find what exactly does Firebase does which is different to unity analytics as I have enabled unity analytics in my game. But unity analytics is not an option to use for google add campaign.

Could anyone here help me understand the process of google add campaign for iOS game/app using Firebase?

Also, is it safe to add Firebase SDK to the published game or it may cause some errors/re-coding?

Tried to find article which explains the link between Unity + Google Ads + Firebase for iOS Game/App but couldn't find any. I am new at developing games and apart from finding my feet in coding, this marketing/ads stuff is totally going above my head with some many different systems needing to make money from games development.

Many thanks for your time and help!

Mr A

P.S Googled but still confused about it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relevant tutorial with step by step instructions and context/explanation of the various components:  [Measure Google Ads conversions from your iOS app campaigns](https://firebase.google.com/docs/tutorials/ads-ios-on-device-measurement)

As for what Firebase Analytics does vs Unity Analytics, Firebase Analytics is built on top of Google Analytics and gives your app access to Google Analytics' robust tooling, data export and integration with other services (such as crash reporting, config rollouts and A/B testing).

More information also available in [Get started with Google Analytics for Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/unity/start). Additionally, to use Google analytics or other services that do tracking on iOS you should also look over [Prepare for iOS 14+](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/ios14)

Finally here are some other general resources for using Firebase:

- [Firebase Documentation for Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity)
- [Example Projects](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity)
- [Example/ Tutorial of Integrating Analytics with Crash Reporting](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/understand-unity-games-crashes-using-advanced-crashlytics?hl=en#0)
- [Example/ Tutorial of Integrating Analytics with A/B Testing](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/instrument-your-game-with-firebase-remote-config#0)